# "error no such device" + grub rescue >

Tags: boot, grub2, bios

Using Ubuntu 16 on an Intel PC, one WD 500 gb disk on SATA0, grub loader, boots fine, no other OS.

Added another WD 500 gb disk on SATA2. It was formatted on Windows 7 and contained lots of data files. When I'd boot I get see the "error no such device [large hex number]" and then the prompt would fall to grub repair>  .

I checked here and elsewhere for a solution and read a lot about how to create mount points and repairing grub etc but they all seemed to be about adding a new disk, not one full of data which I didn't want reformatted.

Any ideas on how to add a disk full of data to an existing system?

Comment: To fit this site's q&a format, this needs to be edited into a question, and then you can post an answer to it.  If you don't do this, it will get closed.

Comment: Done, see the post below.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this I used the BIOS to set the boot order. When adding an identical disk, it shows up in the boot sequence as [SATA: WDC WD5000] two times, and there was no indication which was /dev/sda1. When I moved the second entry to the top of the list, it was the original /dev/sda1 and the machine booted fine.